# How can I delete ignored folder from Bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I need help with removing files from GIT, which was pushed to Bitbucket and now I need to remove them.

**Detailed explanation**

I created project and git push origin master full folder. But after 2 weeks I did some changes and now I want to remove image folder from repository (where are stored images from users). So I added path to .gitignore file (/public/images/). Then push changes to Bitbucket. But problem is, that on Bitbucket repository is still folder /public/images/ and when I deploy on production, there is /public/images/ folder in each version. So I need to delete it from Bitbucket repository, and I don't know how. I thought when I add ignore line in GIT, then it will be automaticaly destroyed from repository.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a simple way to remove unwanted file from Github history?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27761031/is-there-a-simple-way-to-remove-unwanted-file-from-github-history)  The solution would be the same for BitBucket as Github.  You want to remove files that were committed and instead should be ignored.

Comment: I added detailed explanation. Pls look on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood the question you want to remove a folder so that it no longer appears in the latest commit.

.gitignore only cause git to ignore files it isn't already tracking. To remove something you need `git rm`.

Something like `git rm -r /public/images` should stage the removal of the folder which can then be committed and pushed as you would any other change.

Comment: but this solution will also remove the /public/images folder from your local directory